# PHP creating objects inside a base controller on demand

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

So i'm working on a framework (Yes i know it's overdone) and i was brainstorming what would be the best possible approach to achieve dynamic object creation inside a base controller. So i came up with the following solution:

**Base controller**

```
abstract class Controller extends Container
{
    public function __get($obj)
    {
         $this->$obj = $this->get($obj)
         return $this->obj;
    }
{
```

**App controller**

```
class Welcome extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
         $this->view->render('welcome');
    }
}
```

So now let me explain whats happening. The base controller extends a container which is a dependency injection class. It holds closures for creating objects. So when we try to access undefined property in welcome controller it calls the magic __get method.
Then the base controller gets the binding from the DI container and defines it as a property so we can use it.

So everything works exactly as i wanted, but i know that magic methods are slow. I was wondering how would it impact performance when there is dozens of __get calls. Is there a better way of achieving the same thing without defining all classes manually in the base controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that is **not** a *DI Container*. What you have there is a *Service Locator*, which you have inherited. If you user *Service Locator* with some care, it is a quite good pattern, but people usually abuse it and it turns into an architectural anti-pattern.

When you write `extends` in your code, it means that when you write `class B extends A`, you are stating that B is just a special case of A. Controllers are not service locators.

Next .. emm. You seem to be missing the point of controllers withing MVC and MVC-inspired architectures.

> <sub>A **controller** can send commands to the model to update the model's state (e.g., editing a document). It can also send commands to its associated view to change the view's presentation of the model (e.g., by scrolling through a document).</sub>
>
> <kbd>source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller)</kbd>

Basically, what you are trying to attemt would both violate the basic principles of the pattern and also ignore [*Single Responsibility Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You would be turning a controller in some variation on *Factory*.

What this boils down to is: why is your controller producing instance and returning them?

Comment: So if i understand correctly controller should be responsible only for loading models/views. But what about other libraries such as form validation/session etc? Should i create objects inside the base controller as property?

Comment: Not really. Controllers should be only passing the data from user's request to model layer (and in rare cases - to current view). At no point would controllers be instantiating any objects.

Comment: @teresko "At no point would controllers be instantiating any objects" - so how would you pass data to model layer without instantiating (model layer) objects? ... Could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: @Andrew you should never have `new` keyword inside controllers, because it causes tight coupling. Instead the instantiation of services from model layer should be done by some `ServiceFactory` instance, that you passed in the constructor of `Controller` instance (the most optimal solution would be to pass in the required services directly, but that needs a DI container). You could watch [**this lecture**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) and then come back, if you still think that the statement is confusing.

Comment: @tereško Yes, i read and watched that. But using service factory inside controller is the same as instantation of new object(s) inside controller, only hidden inside the wrapper? Isn't it? Where is the benefit of using SF then?

Comment: @Andrew  It lets you test the controller in isolation, because you can pass in a mock. It also lets you share some dependencies between multiple services. And, if your views are requesting data from model layer, then by passing same SF to both view and controller instance, you can make sure that same service is instantiated only once (this making it easier to share the model's state).

Comment: @tereško Yes, i had something like that in my mind, although I'm not sure if you really often test controller as it is very thin and simple... On the other hand, as I understand, you need SF if you instantiate and render View on the bootstrap level. But if you move interaction with Model to Controller level (create Model Layer objects and create View inside Controller) then you can also share same dependencies and share same model state inside controller..?

Comment: @Andrew  Well ... that would merge the controllers and views responsibilities. The point of view is to handle UI logic. Which means that, based on what it get from model layer, the view should be choosing which templates to use, and some of those templates in turn would need additional information from model layer. Basically, what you end up is all of the UI logic being moved into controllers, which then also becomes responsible for juggling the templates.

Comment: @tereško If i instantiate View inside controller, i still have View object encapsulated (because it's an object) and all UI logic and template assignment would be inside this View object. So everything the controller would do is pass some data to the View (if it needs to be done), additionaly View would get main data from the Model Layer, and controller would run $view-render() and that's it. Although View is inside controller, but the View UI logic would be encapsulated from controller logic because of natural scope that class has. What do you think?

Comment: I think that you do not understand what "UI logic" is.

Comment: @tereško could you give me an (code) example of "UI logic" ? (in php, for web)